# Android. RecyclerView поиск по элементам

Tags: android, recyclerview, filter, android-search-view

Использую `RecyclerView` для отображения списка с элементами. Хочу реализовать поиск по этому способу, желательно наиболее простым и действенным способом. Не смог разобраться в тех примерах что нашел в интернете, т.к. сложны для меня (я пока что новичок).
Элемент списка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textId"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@color/poloska_spiska"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
package com.starikov.definitions.adapters;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.starikov.definitions.MainActivity;
import com.starikov.definitions.R;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private int[] textId;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
        public ViewHolder(LinearLayout v){
            super(v);
            mLinearLayout = v;
        }
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(int[] textId){
        this.textId = textId;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LinearLayout cv = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.definition, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        float textSize;
        LinearLayout linearLayout = holder.mLinearLayout;
        TextView textView = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.textId);
        textSize = MainActivity.sharedPreferences.getFloat(MainActivity.APP_PREFERENCES_TEXT_SIZE, 15);
        textView.setTextSize(textSize);
        textView.setText(linearLayout.getResources().getText(textId[position]));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return textId.length;
    }
}
```

Фрагмент со списком `RecyclerView`:

```
package com.starikov.definitions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.starikov.definitions.adapters.RecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.starikov.definitions.definitions.Geometry;

public class GeometryDefinitionFragment extends Fragment {

    private static int themePosition;
    private int[] definitionTexts;
    int formulaId = 0;

    public static void setChoosedTheme(int position){
        themePosition = position;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView formulaRecycler = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.himical_definition_fragment, container, false);

        switch (themePosition){
            case 0:
                definitionTexts = new int[Geometry.ugli.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Geometry.ugli.length; ++i) {
                    definitionTexts[formulaId] = Geometry.ugli[i].getTextId();
                    formulaId++;
                }
                getActivity().setTitle("Углы");
                break;
            case 1:
                definitionTexts = new int[Geometry.parallenie_pryamie.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Geometry.parallenie_pryamie.length; ++i) {
                    definitionTexts[formulaId] = Geometry.parallenie_pryamie[i].getTextId();
                    formulaId++;
                }
                getActivity().setTitle("Параллельные прямые");
                break;
            case 2:
                definitionTexts = new int[Geometry.treugolniki.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Geometry.treugolniki.length; ++i) {
                    definitionTexts[formulaId] = Geometry.treugolniki[i].getTextId();
                    formulaId++;
                }
                getActivity().setTitle("Треугольники");
                break;
            case 3:
                definitionTexts = new int[Geometry.pryamoygolnii_treugolnik.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Geometry.pryamoygolnii_treugolnik.length; ++i) {
                    definitionTexts[formulaId] = Geometry.pryamoygolnii_treugolnik[i].getTextId();
                    formulaId++;
                }
                getActivity().setTitle("Прямоугольный треугольник");
                break;
            case 4:
                definitionTexts = new int[Geometry.gmt.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Geometry.gmt.length; ++i) {
                    definitionTexts[formulaId] = Geometry.gmt[i].getTextId();
                    formulaId++;
                }
                getActivity().setTitle("Геометрические места точек");
                break;
            case 5:
                definitionTexts = new int[Geometry.gomotetia.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Geometry.gomotetia.length; ++i) {
                    definitionTexts[formulaId] = Geometry.gomotetia[i].getTextId();
                    formulaId++;
                }
                getActivity().setTitle("Геометрические места точек");
                break;
            case 6:
                definitionTexts = new int[Geometry.chetirehugolnik.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Geometry.chetirehugolnik.length; ++i) {
                    definitionTexts[formulaId] = Geometry.chetirehugolnik[i].getTextId();
                    formulaId++;
                }
                getActivity().setTitle("Четырехугольники");
                break;
        }

        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(definitionTexts);
        formulaRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        formulaRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return formulaRecycler;
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MainActivity.lastOpenedFragment = new GeometryDefinitionFragment();
        MainActivity.genometryDefinitionFrag = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        MainActivity.genometryDefinitionFrag = false;
    }
}
```

В нем я получаю id с предыдущего фрагмента и для каждого id заполняю список разными элемнтами.

Класс Geometry

```
package com.starikov.definitions.definitions;

import com.starikov.definitions.R;

public class Geometry {
    private int textId;

    public static final Geometry[] ugli = {
            new Geometry(R.string.ugol),
            new Geometry(R.string.razvernutii_ugol),
            new Geometry(R.string.pryamim_uglom),
            new Geometry(R.string.ostrim),
            new Geometry(R.string.tupim),
            new Geometry(R.string.smejnie),
            new Geometry(R.string.gradus),
            new Geometry(R.string.ravnimi),
            new Geometry(R.string.bissektrisa),
            new Geometry(R.string.vertical),
            new Geometry(R.string.uglom_mejdu_dvumya_peresekauch_praymamim),
            new Geometry(R.string.perpendikular),
    };

    public static final Geometry[] parallenie_pryamie = {
            new Geometry(R.string.parallelnie_pryamie),
            new Geometry(R.string.teorema_suh_paral_pryamih),
            new Geometry(R.string.aksioma_paral_pryamih),
            new Geometry(R.string.sledstvie),
            new Geometry(R.string.parallelnie_pryamie_ugli),
            new Geometry(R.string.priznaki_parallelnosti_dvuh_prymih),
            new Geometry(R.string.svoistva_uglov_paral_pr),
            new Geometry(R.string.teorema_faleca),
            new Geometry(R.string.rashrir_faleca),
    };

    public static final Geometry[] treugolniki = {
            new Geometry(R.string.treugolnik),
            new Geometry(R.string.uglom_treugolnika),
            new Geometry(R.string.vidi_treugolnikov),
            new Geometry(R.string.perimetr),
            new Geometry(R.string.sootnoshenie_ejdu_storonami_i_uglami_treugolnika),
            new Geometry(R.string.vneshnim),
            new Geometry(R.string.ravnimi__),
            new Geometry(R.string.priznaki_ravenstva_treugolnikov),
            new Geometry(R.string.srednyaya_linia),
            new Geometry(R.string.mediana),
            new Geometry(R.string.bissektrisa__),
            new Geometry(R.string.visota),
            new Geometry(R.string.svoistvo_srednei_linii_treugolnika),
            new Geometry(R.string.bissektrisa_ravnobedr),
            new Geometry(R.string.chetire_zamechatelnie_tochki_treugolnika),
            new Geometry(R.string.svoistva_median_treugolnika),
            new Geometry(R.string.reshit_treugolnik),
    };

    public static final Geometry[] pryamoygolnii_treugolnik = {
            new Geometry(R.string.pryamougolnii_treugolnik),
            new Geometry(R.string.gipotenuza),
            new Geometry(R.string.kateti),
            new Geometry(R.string.swoistvo_mediani_provedennoi_na_gipotenuzu),
            new Geometry(R.string.priznaki_ravenstva_pryamougolnih_treugolnikov),
            new Geometry(R.string.v_pryamougolnom_treugolnike),
            new Geometry(R.string.teorema_pifagora),
            new Geometry(R.string.obratnaya_teorema_pifagora),
            new Geometry(R.string.teorema_kosinusov),
            new Geometry(R.string.teorema_sinusov),
    };

    public static final Geometry[] gmt = {
            new Geometry(R.string.gmt),
            new Geometry(R.string.okrujnost),
            new Geometry(R.string.seredinnii_perpendikular),
            new Geometry(R.string.sovokupnost_dvuh_pryamih_parallelnoih_dannoi),
            new Geometry(R.string.parallelnaya_im_pruyamaya),
            new Geometry(R.string.sovokupnost_dvuh_pryamih),
            new Geometry(R.string.sovokupnost_dvuh_segmentov_bez_ih_konsov),
    };

    public static final Geometry[] gomotetia = {
            new Geometry(R.string.gomotetia),
            new Geometry(R.string.preobrazovanie_podobia),
            new Geometry(R.string.podobnimi),
            new Geometry(R.string.sushestvovanie_podobnih_treugolnikov),
            new Geometry(R.string.svoistvo_preobrazovania_podobia),
            new Geometry(R.string.priznaki_podobia_treugolnikov),
            new Geometry(R.string.v_podobnih_treugolnikah),
    };

    public static final Geometry[] chetirehugolnik = {
            new Geometry(R.string.chetirehugolnik),
            new Geometry(R.string.vershini_i_storoni),
            new Geometry(R.string.sosednie_protivoleshahie),
            new Geometry(R.string.sosednie_smejnie),
            new Geometry(R.string.diagonal),
            new Geometry(R.string.vipuklim),
            new Geometry(R.string.uglom),
            new Geometry(R.string.sosednie_protivoleshahie_ugli),
            new Geometry(R.string.svoistvo_uglov_vipuklogo_chetirehugolnika),
            new Geometry(R.string.perimetr___),
            new Geometry(R.string.svoistva_parallelograma),
            new Geometry(R.string.priznaki_parallelograma),
            new Geometry(R.string.pryamougolnik),
            new Geometry(R.string.svoistva_pryamougolnika),
            new Geometry(R.string.priaznaki_pryamougolnika),
            new Geometry(R.string.romb),
            new Geometry(R.string.svoistva_romba),
            new Geometry(R.string.prizanki_romba),
            new Geometry(R.string.kvadrat),
            new Geometry(R.string.svoistva_kvadrata),
            new Geometry(R.string.prizmnaki_kvadrata),
            new Geometry(R.string.eche_dva_prianaka_kvadrata),
            new Geometry(R.string.trapecia),
            new Geometry(R.string.osnovanie_trapecii),
            new Geometry(R.string.srednyaya_linia_trapecii),
            new Geometry(R.string.diagonal_trapecii),
            new Geometry(R.string.visota_trapecii),
            new Geometry(R.string.svoistva_trapecii),
            new Geometry(R.string.ravnobokoi_rapeciei),
            new Geometry(R.string.pryamougolnoi_trapeciei),
            new Geometry(R.string.svoistva_ravnobokoi_trapecii),
    };

    private Geometry(int textId){
        this.textId = textId;
    }

    public int getTextId(){
        return textId;
    }
}
```

Прошу помощи, т.к. сам не разобрался.

Comment: у вас почти все списки на экран поместятся. Вы в выводимом списке что-то предложите пользователю приложения найти? Вам нужен searchview, сажать на него слушатель и обновлять адаптер

Comment: @TimurVI я хочу просто узнать как посадить на него слушатель, и обновить адаптер. Сам разобраться в этом не смог

Comment: @TimurVI я просто не смог разобраться в том как сделать Filter

Comment: в общем вне фрагмента у вас будет строка поиска, верно?

Comment: Да. Я сейчас пытаюсь просто понять принцип.

Comment: немного занят, вот [здесь](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&hl=ru&dcr=0&ei=3qNIWqPkHMmr6AS33KKIDg&q=android+recyclerview+in+fragment+example+searchview&oq=android+recyclerview+in+fragment+example+search&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.33i22i29i30k1.1978518.1996317.0.1997755.42.27.6.0.0.0.258.3484.0j21j2.23.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..13.29.3502...0j0i10i1i42k1j0i10i1k1j0i10k1j0i67k1j0i22i30k1.0.9WLrHIQvgVw) наверняка что-нибудь найдется

Comment: @TimurVI Все сделал, разобрался, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: оформите ответ пжл, а именно как решили и будут вам плюсы. Возможно кому-то пригодится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, сделал:

activity_main.xml
Тут макет для RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/formula_recycler"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/vertical_scrollview_track"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollview_thumb"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />
```

android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollview_thumb" 
и
android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/vertical_scrollview_track"
мои собственные макеты для полосы прокрутки (можно убрать, можно заменить своими)

MainActivity

```
package com.starikov.search;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Formula> mArrayList = new ArrayList<Formula>(Formula.physicalFormuls.length);
    private RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.formula_recycler); 
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager); 
        mArrayList = setArray(mArrayList); // Заполняем список
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mArrayList); // Создаем адаптер
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); // Подключаем адаптер
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search); // Подключаем SearchView
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
        search(searchView);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void search(SearchView searchView) {

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    private ArrayList<Formula> setArray(ArrayList<Formula> list) { // Заполняю ArrayList готовым списком из класса Formula
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(Formula.physicalFormuls));
        return list;
    }
}
```

main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Formula.java

```
package com.starikov.search;

public class Formula {
    private String name;
    private int imageId;

    public Formula(String name, int imageId){
        this.name = name;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }



    public static final Formula[] physicalFormuls = { // Текст по которому будет вестись поиск, и картинка которую ищем
            new Formula("закон движения", R.drawable.formul_zakon_dvijenia),
            new Formula("координатные уравнения движения", R.drawable.formul_koordinatnie_uravneniya_dvigenia),
            new Formula("перемещение точки тела",R.drawable.formul_peremechenie), 
            ....
    };

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getImageId(){
        return imageId;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

card_view.xml (макет для элемента списка)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/info_image"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
package com.starikov.search;

import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable{

    private ArrayList<Formula> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Formula> mFilteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    mFilteredList = mArrayList;
                } else {
                    ArrayList<Formula> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Formula formula : mArrayList) {
                        if (formula.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) { // Сортируем по тексту из Formula
                            filteredList.add(formula); 
                        }
                    }
                    mFilteredList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mFilteredList = (ArrayList<Formula>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private CardView mCardView;
        private ImageView imageView;
        public ViewHolder(CardView v){
            super(v);
            mCardView = v;
            imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.info_image);
        }
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Formula> arrayList){
        mArrayList = arrayList;
        mFilteredList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(holder.mCardView.getResources().getDrawable(mFilteredList.get(position).getImageId()));
        holder.imageView.setContentDescription(mFilteredList.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }
}
```

в Gradle зависимости для CardView и RecyclerView

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

Буду рад советам как улучшить код!

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю так: searchView. сам фрагмент. Если ничего не находит, то вывожу текст вью с надписью - НЕ найдено.

```
// поиск
public class MyFragment
        extends Fragment
        implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
//
//фрагепмнт


 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        searchView.clearFocus();
        return false;
    }

    private List<ItemListStation>
    filter(List<ItemListStation> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        final List<ItemListStation> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ItemListStation model : models)     {
            final String text;
            text = model.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

        final List<ItemListStation> filteredModelList = filter(listStationItemList, newText);
        adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
        textViewSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (filteredModelList.isEmpty()) {
            View myView = textViewSearch;
            slideToBottom(myView);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void slideToBottom(View view){
        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.shake);
        if (view.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.startAnimation(shake);
        }
    }
```

A этот метод прописываю в адаптере:

```
void setFilter(List<ItemListStation> listStationItemLists)   {
    itemListStations = new ArrayList<>();
    itemListStations.addAll(listStationItemLists);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="?attr/layoutBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSearch"
        style="?attr/colorBlueText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:text="Ничего не найдено"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```